# ESP-01 and chipkit PIC32 project

Tags: jquery, html, wifi, pic32

Hello every one I'm currently doing a University project. I'm trying to make a wifi Morse code translator. Basically I have a webpage where I put a string and send it to the ESP01. The ESP01 then sends it to the PIC32 microcontroller who then controls a LED to show my string as morse code.

Material is non exchangeable

I'm running into a few problems:

-can't find  a library for the ESP01 that is compatible with PIC32

this makes it impossible for me to contact the module and set it up correctly

-I'm trying to set it up in UART mode, however I'm screwing up the pin setup even after reading the schematics

-I'm having trouble with the html code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ESP8266 LED Control</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- in the <button> tags below the ID attribute is the value sent to the arduino -->

    <button id="13" class="led">Turn LED ON</button> 
    <button id="13" class="led">Turn LED OFF</button> 


    <form <input type="text" id="txt_name" value="" />
    <button id="act" >Send</button> 

    $('#act').click(getstring);

    function getstring(){
        $("input").attr("value");
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Replace all with `name`
        $('td:contains("i have to print the name inside here")').text(value);
     }

</body>
</html>
```

This is the basic setup (0 communication with module) I want a text input box where i can get said text and send it over. appart from the buttons thsi is kind of frankenstein's monster code from different places. It's my first html/jQuery project. Any help however small is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many basic things wrong with your code. I suggest you read a bit about Javascript, HTML and Jquery before working. I tidied up whatever I could to make it work minimally as per your requirement. Hopefully you can build further on it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Replace all with `name`
  //$('td:contains("i have to print the name inside here")').text(value);
})
$('#act').click(getstring);

function getstring() {
  var value = $("#txt_name").val();
  alert(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- in the <button> tags below the ID attribute is the value sent to the arduino -->

<button id="ledOn" class="led">Turn LED ON</button>
<button id="ledOff" class="led">Turn LED OFF</button>

<br/>
<br/>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="txt_name" name="txt_name" value="" />
  <button id="act">Send</button>
</form>
```